# writing results of sql query to dataframe with scala fails in databricks

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

just running this spark-sql query in databricks works fine:

```
%sql
select CONCAT(`tsArr[1]`,"-", `tsArr[0]`,"-", `tsArr[2]`," ", `tsArr[3]`) as time,
  cast (context._function as string) as funct, 
  cast (context._param as string) as param, 
  cast(context._value as string) as value from clickstreamDF
  lateral view explode(Context) as context
```

this outputs:

```
time                funct   param           value
11-27-2017 08:20:33 Open    location        3424
11-27-2017 08:20:33 Open    Company Id      testinc
11-27-2017 08:20:33 Open    Channel Info    1
11-27-2017 08:20:33 Open    UserAgent       jack
11-27-2017 08:20:33 Open    Language        english
```

but when I want to put the query result in a dataframe like this

```
%scala    
val df_header = spark.sql(s"select CONCAT(`tsArr[1]`,"-", `tsArr[0]`,"-", `tsArr[2]`," ", `tsArr[3]`) as time,
  cast (context._function as string) as funct,
  cast (context._param as string) as param,
  cast(context._value as string) as value
  from clickstreamDF lateral view explode(Context) as context")

df_header.createOrReplaceTempView("clickstreamDF")
```

then it fails. It says:

> error: ')' expected but string literal found.

I'm guessing it has to do with the "-" and " ". I have tried replacing or extending with '' and `` or leaving "" away completely but without result.
what am I doing wrong?

regards,

D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid ambiguity between the quotes (i.e. `"`) for enclosing the entire Spark SQL string versus those used within your SQL statement, use triple-quotes (`"""`) for the enclosing quotes.  You would also need to remove the `backticks` that enclose those `tsArr[]`s, as shown in the following example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

case class CT(_function: String, _param: String, _value: String)

val clickstreamDF = Seq(
  (Seq("27", "11", "2017", "08:20:33"), Seq(CT("f1", "p1", "v1"), CT("f2", "p2", "v2"))),
  (Seq("28", "12", "2017", "09:30:44"), Seq(CT("f3", "p3", "v3")))
).toDF("tsArr", "contexts")

clickstreamDF.createOrReplaceTempView("clickstreamTable")

val df_header = spark.sql("""
  select
    concat(tsArr[1], "-", tsArr[0], "-", tsArr[2], " ", tsArr[3]) as time,
    cast(context._function as string) as funct,
    cast(context._param as string) as param,
    cast(context._value as string) as value
  from
    clickstreamTable lateral view explode(contexts) as context
""")

df_header.show
// +-------------------+-----+-----+-----+
// |               time|funct|param|value|
// +-------------------+-----+-----+-----+
// |11-27-2017 08:20:33|   f1|   p1|   v1|
// |11-27-2017 08:20:33|   f2|   p2|   v2|
// |12-28-2017 09:30:44|   f3|   p3|   v3|
// +-------------------+-----+-----+-----+
```

BTW, you might want to consider using the DataFrame API since you already have the data in a DataFrame:

```
val df_header = clickstreamDF.
  withColumn("time",
    concat($"tsArr"(1), lit("-"), $"tsArr"(0), lit("-"), $"tsArr"(2), lit(" "), $"tsArr"(3))
  ).
  withColumn("context", explode($"contexts")).
  select($"time",
    $"context._function".cast("String").as("funct"),
    $"context._param".cast("String").as("param"),
    $"context._value".cast("String").as("value")
  )
```

Comment: Hi Leo, Thanks for helping me out. your support is very much appreciated! works like a charm.